# Office 365 - SharePoint Online - Get Taxonomy Group Name of Page Properties using PowerShell CSOM

Tags: powershell, office-365, csom, taxonomy, term-store

I have a requirement where I need to find the `Taxonomy Field assigned to a page property`.

For Example, `Language` is a page property and `Unity is the group name` assigned to it and `Language is the termset` for that property.

Now, I need to find that dynamically to know what group is assigned to the page property using PowerShell.

I have cast it into a taxonomy field and got 2 properties like `SspId` and `TermSetId`. By using the `SspId`, I was able to find the termstore properly, but not the group and the termset.

My Code :

```
$TaxFldLanguage = $pagesList.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Language");
$ctx.Load($TaxFldLanguage);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

#casting here
$objTxFieldOffice = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("CastTo").MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]).Invoke($ctx, $TaxFldOffice);

$termStoreID = $objTxFieldOffice.SspId.ToString();
$termSetID = $objTxFieldOffice.TermSetId.ToString();

#find the termstore and the matching termsetID
$termStores = $TaxonomySession.TermStores.GetById($termStoreID);
$ctx.Load($termStores);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

if ($termStores) {
    $termStore = $termStores[0];
    $Groups = $termStore.Groups;
    $ctx.Load($termStore);
    $ctx.Load($Groups);
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach ($grp in $Groups) {
        #loop through all termsets in all groups and check with the $termSetID
        $grpTermsets = $grp.TermSets;
        $ctx.Load($grpTermsets);
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach ($trmset in $grpTermsets) {
            Write-Host "Termset: " + $trmset.Name -ForegroundColor Gray;
            $terms = $trmset.Terms;
            $ctx.Load($terms);
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach ($trm in $terms) {
                Write-Host $trm.Id -ForegroundColor Blue;
                if ($trm.Id -eq $termSetID) {
                    Write-Host "Group: "+ $grp.Name + "Termset:"+ $trmset.Name -ForegroundColor DarkRed;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got the termstore and termset assigned to the page property.

```
#load TermStore here
$TaxonomySession = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($ctx);
$TermStore = $TaxonomySession.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
$ctx.Load($TaxonomySession);
$ctx.Load($TermStore);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

#get page property
$TaxFldLanguageB = $pagesList.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("LanguageB");
$ctx.Load($TaxFldLanguageB);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

#cast to taxonomy
$objTxFieldOffice = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("CastTo").MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]).Invoke($ctx, $TaxFldLanguageB);

#get termstore and termset id
$termStoreID = $objTxFieldOffice.SspId.ToString();
$termSetID = $objTxFieldOffice.TermSetId.ToString();

$termsetData = $TermStore.GetTermSet($termSetID);
$ctx.Load($termsetData);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

$termsData = $termsetData.Terms;
$ctx.Load($termsData);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach ($objTerm in $termsData) {
    Write-Host $objTerm.Name " - " $objTerm.Id;
}
```